# Can I pay my baby an income to max out a custodial Roth IRA without paying/filing taxes for him?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, children

I made a huge income jump from a career move right after having a baby. I do not want to do any lifestyle creeping and would rather put this money to work with compound interest. I'll already be maxing out my and my wife's Roth IRA and Roth 401k, and I already contribute to a 529. I have more excess money that I want to save on behalf of my children. I'm trying to figure out the best method of doing so.

I know the following:

1. You can open a Roth IRA for a minor, a "custodial" account.
2. If you make less than the standard, you do not have to pay taxes

This leads me to assume that I would be able to pay my baby a salary of 6,000 a year to, for example, visit his grandparents, which will be enough to fill up his Custodial Roth IRA, and the money will not have to be taxed because it's below the standard deduction. Is this the case? If so, what would I need to do exactly? Would I even need to file a W2?

Comment: What work will your baby be doing in order to earn this $6,000 a year?

Comment: That would be one of my questions, I guess. He visits his grandparents, who are very happy to see him, very frequently. I was thinking that could be one route. Visitations, I guess?

Comment: #1 Child labor laws preclude them working.  #2 **You're not the first to think of this.**  How do I know?  Because if it was legal all the other rich people would be doing it.

Comment: @RonJohn - I am just playing Devil's Advocate here - How do child actors get paid? Or child models. That's income, right?

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica their work is strictly regulated and a PITA for studios and modeling agencies (which is why Dawson Casting exists).

Comment: Understood. I was just making a point. But ultimately, I agree with you and reflected that in my answer.

Comment: @RonJohn: Err... Do we know that all the other rich people don't do it?  Of course $6K/year might not be worth bothering with if you're really rich :-)

Comment: Is the Roth account even worth the potential hassles?  Considering that the capital gains tax rate is zero up to $40K income, and low beyond that, just putting the money into long-term investments would seem to involve minimal taxes while the kid is under age.  Then when they're young adults and presumably not earning much, they could move it to their own accounts with little tax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just gift them the money (maybe into a UGMA/UTMA account).  It won't earn <s>$12000</s> yearly dividends and cap gains for a long, long, *long* time.

EDIT: parents must pay taxes on their children's custodial accounts [after $1100](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/custodialaccount.asp).  10% from $1101 to $2200 and the parents' rate after that.

Answer (score 5):

I applaud you for thinking ahead. I'd consider RonJohn's answer, but keep in mind when children are of an age they can actually work, you can deposit 100% (up to the maximum Roth limit each year) into the Roth.

This was the process I used to fund my daughter's Roth starting at age 12 or so. Legit good income babysitting. Documented to be audit friendly, names, date/time, payement, etc. She graduated college this year with just north of $65,000 in the Roth. A great head start on her retirement savings.

Comment: So, your daughter actually made $5000 (or whatever the IRA contribution limit was when your daughter was 12 years old) each year? Properly documented as to names, dates and times of payment? Wow!

Comment: The $65K includes return. I’ve invested it well. The first few years deposits started at about $2000. Even at 12, she was getting $10/hr.